# Javascript array value in Jquery [fixed it]

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, variables, web

So, i have a problem. The function should get #content the height of the value of the first variable of the array.
I tried a lot of different ways, but i couldn't get it right.

```
var contentHeight = ["Height1", "Height2", "Height3", "Height4", "Height5", "Height6"];
var contentSelection = 0;
var Height1 = 200;
var Height2 = 400;
var Height3 = 600;
var Height4 = 800;
var Height5 = 1000;
var Height6 = 1200;

function someFunction(){
   $('#content').animate({'height' : contentHeight[contentSelection] +'px'},500);
}
```

Thank you,

Comment: where is the array? I don't see the array `contentHeight`.

Comment: somehow i deleted it, but i fixed it now

Comment: The contentHeight array is not a key => value array, it's just a generic array of strings. You can either remove the brackets from the strings by declaring the Height values before the array OR do that in a more responsive way. Note that in this way you will need to access to the array values using an integer (like you did), but you will not really have a clear idea of the data you're getting, not sure if what you're planning.

Comment: Thank you for the reply briosheje, I tried to get a different height for each page on my page. So if you clicked a button in the menu the content would adjust its height depending on the content thats in it. But i have to try it in another way then

Comment: The content will automatically resize according to the div (in your case to your #content div) css properties. I would personally recommend you to first setup a pretty comfortable and responsive CSS for your #content div and then, eventually, use javascript for some action. What do you mean by "adjusting the height depending on the content"? Can you be more precise about what you mean by "content"? perhaps we can help you more for such a case ;)

Comment: I just fixed it with some inefficient jquery coding. Its fine though. So, no need for help anymore. But Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var Height1 = 200;
var Height2 = 400;
var Height3 = 600;
var Height4 = 800;
var Height5 = 1000;
var Height6 = 1200;
var contentHeight = [Height1, Height2, Height3, Height4, Height5, Height6];
var contentSelection = 0;

function someFunction(){
   $('#content').animate({'height' : contentHeight[contentSelection] +'px'},500);
}
```

or simply this:

```
contentHeight = [];
for (var i = 200; i <= 1200; i+=200) {
 contentHeight.push(i);
}
var contentSelection = 0;

function someFunction(){
    $('#content').animate({'height' : contentHeight[contentSelection] +'px'},500);
}
```

Despite this will work, you should (in my opinion) use a different approach for such a situation. using an index to access the values doesn't give you any clue of the value you're getting, so you may want to change the code (and the array structure) according to what you have to do.

Answer (score 0):

The array contentHeight seems to be missing for holding your values. Maybe it was just assumed. I am adding it for completion but it should work.

Personally I would also consider a dictionary type of object as well.

```
var Height1 = 200;
var Height2 = 400;
var Height3 = 600;
var Height4 = 800;
var Height5 = 1000;
var Height6 = 1200;

var contentHeightArray1 = [200,400, 600, 800, 1000, 1200];

var contentHeightArray2 = [Height1,Height2, Height3, Height4, Height5, Height6 ];

var contentHeightDictionary = {
'Height1':200,
'Height2':400,
'Height3':600,
'Height4':800,
'Height5':1000,
'Height6':1200
};

function someFunction(in_params){
   $('#content').animate({'height' :in_params.contentList[in_params.heightIndex] +'px'},500);
}

var contentSelection = 0;
someFunction({contentList:contentHeightArray1, heightIndex:contentSelection});

contentSelection = 3;
someFunction({contentList:contentHeightArray2, heightIndex:contentSelection});

contentSelection = 'Height5';
someFunction({contentList:contentHeightDictionary, heightIndex:contentSelection});

someFunction({contentList:contentHeightDictionary, heightIndex:'Height6'});
```